# MySQL: where count is higher than average

Tags: mysql, count, left-join, average

I want to select posts from users who have specific followers which is higher than the overall average (compared to other users)

The problem is when I use `AVG()` it limits the number of posts/users coming through, yet I can't use `GROUP BY j.id` as it will break the average count and  `WHERE j2.fCount >= j2.oAvg` stops working properly

Here's my code

```
SELECT * FROM ( 

    SELECT j.*, ROUND(AVG(j.fCount)) as oAvg
   FROM ( 

   SELECT  p.id , COUNT(fCount.id)  as fCount
 FROM `post` p

LEFT JOIN `table` table ON  ...
LEFT JOIN `user` user ON ....
LEFT JOIN `follow` fCount ON fCount.user_id=user.id AND fCount.follow_id=table.ids
WHERE p.user_id=fCount.user_id
group by p.id


) j 
 ---- >   `GROUP BY j.id` - BREAKS THE AVERAGE BELOW 
 ) j2


WHERE j2.fCount >= j2.oAvg
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you're trying to compare to average, you might have to do your inner query twice like this.

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT AVG(fCount) as average FROM
      (SELECT COUNT(fCount.id) as fCount
       FROM post p
       LEFT JOIN follow fCount ON fCount.user_id = p.user_id
       GROUP BY p.id
       )j1
   )as average
FROM
  (SELECT p2.id, COUNT(fCount2.id) as fCount
    FROM post p2
    LEFT JOIN follow fCount2 ON fCount2.user_id = p2.user_id
    GROUP BY p2.id
 )j2
HAVING fCount >= average
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e96f61/15)
just replace inner queries of j1 and j2 with your j

if you just want to run inner query once you can use user-defined variables to total up your count divide it by count to calculate your own average like this

```
SELECT id,fCount,@sum/@count as average
FROM
(SELECT id,
       fCount,
       @sum := @sum + fCount as total,
       @count := @count + 1 as posts
 FROM
      (SELECT p.id,COUNT(fCount.id) as fCount
       FROM post p
       LEFT JOIN follow fCount ON fCount.user_id = p.user_id
       GROUP BY p.id
       )j,
       (SELECT @sum:=0.0,@count:=0.0)initialize
)T
HAVING fCount >= average
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/519de3/1)

Comment: Thank you, but is there a more efficient way of doing this? instead of counting it twice

Comment: I don't think there is a way...but i could be wrong

Comment: i guess if you really wanted to you could create a store procedure that creates your j table as a temporary table. then query on that j table and then when the store proc is done you can drop it.  i don't know how else you can do it without querying that inner table twice

Comment: I found a way with user-defined variables ...check bottom of my answer

Comment: just replace j with your inner query j